# Why is docker compose so much faster than using a Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When I run `docker build .`, it sends the entire directory (minus .dockerignore, I suppose) to the docker context before doing anything else:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  411.9MB
```

However, if I make a docker-compose file that performs the same steps, it doesn't seem to send anything to the docker context. What is the difference between the two, and why would I use a normal dockerfile if docker-compose is always so much faster?

Example dockerfile:

```
# Step 1: compile front end
# use NPM image
FROM node:10-alpine as webui
WORKDIR /webui

# NPM dependencies
COPY ./webui/package.json ./webui/yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install

# Copy web ui code
COPY ./webui .

# Build -> outputs to ./public
ARG GIT_HASH=GIT_HASH
ARG LAST_UPDATED=LAST_UPDATED
ARG API_HOST=API_HOST
RUN yarn run build:production

# Step 2: Compile Server
# Use NPM Image
FROM node:10-alpine
WORKDIR /server

# Npm dependencies
COPY ./server/package.json ./server/yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install

# Copy server code and compile
COPY ./server .
RUN yarn run build:production

# Include the webui compiled above
COPY --from=webui /public/ /public

# Run server
EXPOSE 8080
CMD node /server/dist/index.js
```

Sample docker compose:

```
version: "3.5"

volumes:
  server_node_modules:
  webui_node_modules:

  server-base: &server-base
    image: node:10-alpine
    working_dir: /server
    volumes:
      - ./server:/server
      - ./public:/public
      - server_node_modules:/server/node_modules

  server-install:
    <<: *server-base
    command: "yarn install"

  server-serve:
    <<: *server-base
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    command: "yarn run local"

  webui-base: &webui-base
    image: node:10-alpine
    working_dir: /webui
    volumes:
      - ./webui:/webui
      - ./public:/webui/dist
      - webui_node_modules:/webui/node_modules

  webui-install:
    <<: *webui-base
    command: "yarn install"

  webui-build:
    <<: *webui-base
    command: "yarn run build:local"

  webui-prod:
    <<: *webui-base
    command: "yarn run build:production"

  webui-dev:
    <<: *webui-base
    command: "yarn run dev:watch"
```

In this case, I would run `docker-compose up -d server-serve webui-prod` to accomplish the same thing as the dockerfile (more or less.) So what is the context for, and does docker compose not need it?

Comment: Can I see your `docker-compose.yml`? Do you have a `build:` step in it?

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't have a build step in it. I'll edit my question to clarify.